# Using Auto Increment with MySQL, NHibernate and C#

Tags: c#, mysql, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

**EDIT - 
It turns our the problem was completely unrelated to the primary key mapping - the errors were pointing me in the wrong direction in this particular instance.**

I'm trying to have a simple auto_incremented primary key map to a property in c#.  Here's my hbm mapping I have at the moment:

```
<class name="Lobby" table="lobby">
    <id name="Id" type="int" unsaved-value="null" >
        <column name="id" not-null="true"/>
        <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>

...

</class>
```

And here's my class:

```
public class Lobby
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    ...

}
```

The table is declared as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `lobby`
(
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,

    ...


)
```

When I try to create an object using the repository:

```
using (var session = mSessionFactory.OpenSession())
using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    session.Save(newEntry);
    transaction.Commit();
}
```

I get a PropertyTypeException:

> Exception occurred getter of Lobby.Id>
>   Object does not match target type.

I've tried changing the property to a long and a short and this hasn't helped.  I've also tried making the column not `auto_incremented` and using the "increment" generator, but this generates an insert query that doesn't include the 'id' property, which then fails because the Primary Key needs to be set.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong and are there any examples of how to do this properly?

Comment: This issue is very often related to real type wrong mapping. Mostly, if the string or guid column is mapped to int or secondly if Reference Type is interchanged with int... So please, try to really deeply check that your types do match... NHibernate is predictable ;) I've seen your update.. but still... maybe you target different DB... or...

Comment: As far as I can tell they do - int == "int" == INT.  The type seems to map fine when it's not auto_incremented, it's only when it's set to auto_increment on the table that it throws this error.

Comment: Hmmmm... weird, really. In fact somehting is strange in your question: *..."increment" generator, but this generates an insert query that doesn't include the 'id' property...* I would expect exactly the opposite, because increment will ALWAYS issue insert into ID column (becuase NHibernate does insert, not DB)

Comment: Bok, suggestion: Could you create brand new table change your mapping to that table and check it? I realy suspect some "unrevealed" handling (wrong connection string, wrong db, wrong table)

Comment: This seems to make no difference either.

Comment: Sorry, sir, no more ideas ;(... BE SURE that I of course were testing the same locally... but with SQL Server... and all was working.. but SQL server is not your case ;(

Answer (score 0):

`int` cannot be null. You can try `unsaved-value="0"`.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't make any difference.